# sharp develop can't open web applications written with vs 2010

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, sharpdevelop

My colleague sent me a web project written in Visual Studio 2010. I only have Sharp Develop. when I open the project, I get a number of error messages:

> `The imported project "c:\program files(x86)\MsBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplication\Microsoft.WebApploication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path....`

See:

[image: Showing error messages in the editor]

What do I need to do to fix this??

Comment: Can you add warning/error as text as it's not fully visible in picture? Seems those projects have some Build related settings that are supported by visual studio & not by SharpDevelop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install the [Visual Web Developer Express 2010](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=167874), it should install all the required libraries to your system. You can then use Visual Web Express to edit the solution, but chances are high that Sharp Develop will also be able to open it.

If you want a little more up-to-date editing experience, you can try upgrading the solution to [Visual Studio Express for Web 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40747) by installing that and resolving any upgrade issues that might come from that.